# More than one sub folder in content organiser rule

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, content-organizer, content-organizer-rule

I have a client who has a requirement that documents sent to their record centre are stored as such:

Department Library
 - Country (folder)
    - Fund (folder)
      - Doc Type (folder)

Country, Fund, Doc Type are all managed metadata TermSets. I know out of the box, the content organiser rules only allow you create one sub folder level. So I would only be able to store at the country level in my example.

Has anyone come across or got a solution to this issue? I am looking at finding a solution that is simple as possible. So far i have considered the following solutions:

- Remove the Content Organiser and create a custom ItemAdded event handler on the drop off library, but this presents the problem that ItemAdded fires after upload of document and potentially before the user has captured their metadata.
- Custom Workflow on each library to create the extra levels if needed, and move the document into them.
- Somehow to build a custom Content Organiser rule that will enable this, which would more than likely require some form of Custom router as well.